# Retrieve value from exception handling e in java

Tags: java, object, exception, try-catch

I'm interested to check for exception value and if i have status set to specific value then would like to return / set currency string to respective ERROR, which can be user to throw error in client side.

```
/*code snippet */

       cr.setName(Name);
       cr.setContact(User);
       cr.setValue(Value);
       cr.setStatus(status);

       try
            {
                currency = (serviceCountry.createCurrencyTicket( cr, null ));

                if ( testPattern( currency ) )
                {
                    return currency;
                }

            }
            catch ( Exception e )
            {
                this.logger.log( Level.WARNING,
                                "Exception occured while evaluating currency = "
                                                + currency, params );                
            }
```

for example, Exception e has response, cause, stackTrace object. i would like to retrieve value from response and set currency to specific ERROR. Something like

```
catch ( Exception e )
{
  if ( e.getClass().getName().getStatus() == 2 )
   {
    currency = 'ERROR';
   } else if ( e.getClass().getName().getStatus() == 0 )
   {
    currency = 'DOWN';
   }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? What problem are you facing?

Comment: `e.getClass().getName().getStatus()`??? What does it means. AFIK `getName` returns a String and String doesn't have a `getStatus`

Comment: Catching `Exception` to start with is bad practice; you'd better catch more specific exceptions first. `Exception` also catches unchecked exceptions...

Comment: I'm not able to do this e.getClass().getName().getStatus(), i don't find getStatus() method.

Comment: @Mad-D is your function throwing a custom Exception?

Comment: The "status" seems to be stored in this object:  `cr`.  Do something like `cr.getStatus()` instead?

Comment: @nachokk: i was trying to give an example, i'm interested to retrieve value from exception e

Comment: First you should a specific exception from `createCurrencyTicket`. If you have control in that method you should throw from there exceptions it could be, ErrorException, DownException then you know what message or simple a CurrencyException with a property `type` that could be `ERROR`, `DOWN` etc.. If you can't handle IOException or that type you can put `DOWN`..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Catching the actual type of Exception thrown is one option

```
try
{
     currency = (serviceCountry.createCurrencyTicket( cr, null ));
}catch(MyCustomException ex)
{
     if( ex.getStatus() == 2 )
         currency = "Oh Nos";
     else if( ex.getStatus() == 0 )
         currency = "Ehh";
}catch(Exception e)
{
     currency = "SuperBad";
}
```

Another, although tedious option, would be to check the type of the thrown Exception

```
try
{
     currency = (serviceCountry.createCurrencyTicket( cr, null ));
}catch(Exception e)
{
     if( e instanceof MyCustomException )
     {
         MyCustomException customEx = (MyCustomException)e;
         if( customEx.getStatus() == 2 )
             currency = "Oh Nos";
         else if( customEx.getStatus() == 0 )
             currency = "Ehh";
     }
     else
         currency = "SuperBad";
}
```

Comment: But that second scheme is a good one to understand, since it's valuable in other areas unrelated to exceptions.